# Component is re-rendering although value in zustand store do not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, zustand

I'm trying to implement Zustand into my app to avoid unnecessary re-rerendering and improve the performance of my app. For this I created a testStore:

```
const useTestStore = create((set) => ({
  settings: {},
  updateSettings: (key, value) => {
    set((state) => ({
      settings: {
        ...state.settings,
        [key]: {
          ...state.settings[key],
          ...value,
        },
      },
    }));
  },
}));
```

Initially the store will be filled with a json file containing some data. Its not deeply nested and looks like this:

```
{
  "app": {
    "defaultPage": {
      "value": "Home",
      "label": "Start Page",
      "options": [
        "Home",
        "Dashboard",
        "Settings"
      ]
    },
    "textSize": {
      "value": "Default",
      "label": "Text Size",
      "options": [
        "Small",
        "Default",
        "Large"
      ]
    },
  },
  "side_bars": {
    "label": "SideBar Settings",
    "topBarHeight": {
      "value": 40,
      "label": "TopBar Height"
    },
    "navBarHeight": {
      "value": 65,
      "label": "NavBar Height"
    }
  }
}
```

Now for example in my NavBar component I try to subscribe to a slice of this store like this:

```
const app = useTestStore((state) => state.settings.app)
```

I would expect the component to only re-render if a value under the key "app" changed, based on the documentation of zustand. But my component re-renders also when I change a value under the side_bars key and even if I dont change any values at all. Based on the react development tools it's definitely the hook thats causing the render. I'm changing the values in my settings component where I'm modifying a copy of the store object and then write it back to the store:

```
const updateTestStore = useTestStore((state) => state.updateSettings);

Object.entries(currentSettings).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      updateTestStore(key, value);
    });
```

When I change my store setup to something like this, subscribing to a slice works, but using Zustand this should not be necessary right?

```
const useTestStore = create((set) => ({
  settings: {},
  updateSettings: (key, value) => {
    set((state) => {
      // Check if the new value is different from the existing value
      if (JSON.stringify(state.settings[key]) !== JSON.stringify(value)) {
        return {
          settings: {
            ...state.settings,
            [key]: {
              ...state.settings[key],
              ...value,
            },
          },
        };
      }
      return state;
    });
  },
}));
```

I also already tried using shallow and useShallow but without success. I was hoping that zustand would make this a bit easier but maybe I'm also just missing some key information here?

Comment: Intuitively I would have said that you indeed need useShallow, since you are working with nested objects. What did you tried exactly? Can you show , by updating the post?

Comment: I'm new too Zustand. I think it re-render because you are making a new object when when you update `app`. I believe you can `useMemo` with "app" key as the dependency. So your render function will used the memorized "state.settings.app" to prevent re-render